# Keyboard pressing a key like a Ghost in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard

I Have a key in my keyboard that's don't work: **/?**

Although physically exists, this key does not work and to use these characters I have to type **Alt gr + Q** and **Alt gr + W** respectively

But randomly the / character begins typing as if the key had been pressed and held, repeating the character indefinitely like a ghost.

> Linux vinicius-note 5.3.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18
>   05:37:46 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

My etc/default/keyboard

> XKBMODEL="pc105"
>   XKBLAYOUT="br" 
>   XKBVARIANT="" 
>   XKBOPTIONS=""
>
> BACKSPACE="guess"

Is this a hardware or software failure?

My correct Keyboard Layout is abnt2

Comment: The way to tell if this is software or hardware failure is to acquire another known-working keyboard (temporarily is fine, borrow it from a neighbor), unplug the trouble keyboard, and plug in the known-working keyboard.  Try the same test.  If the problem continues with the good keyboard, the problem is probably software.  If it doesn't, it's probably hardware.  If it's a software problem, you might also try booting into a LiveCD to see if the problem keyboard keeps having issues, to see if your layout or some other customization is causing it.

Comment: After install Ubuntu 20.04 from a fresh install, the / key worked perfectly

Comment: And Ghost keypress is not occuring

Comment: Forget.  The problem returned in Ubuntu 20.04 today.  It can only be some update.  It was working completely Normal !!

Comment: When I plug a external USB keyboard, the original keyboard in the notebook don't cause ghost keypress, and I can use the 2 keyboards normally

Comment: OBS: And the problem now is with ~ ghost keypress, the / continues ok.